# How do I find the segment, created by joining any pair of points, with maximum slope?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Given n 2D points. Consider all possible segments which are created by joining any pair of these points. How do I find the segment with the maximum slope among all possible segments in O(n*log(n))?

Can we sort the array based on x- and/or y-coordinates?

1. Find the `y_i` and  `y_j` such that `y_i - y_j` is the maximum difference, and find the slope (let it be `delta_y`);
2. find the `x_k` and `x_l` such that `x_k - x_l` is minimum, and find the slope (let it be `delta_x`);
3. return x and y coordinates `max(delta_y, delta_x)`.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can. Consider three consecutive points. Draw the line from the first to the third point, and look at whether the middle point is above, at or below it. If the middle point is on the line, all slopes are equal. If the middle point is above the line, then the slope from the first to the second point is the highest. If the middle point is below the line, then the slope from the middle point to the second is highest. In any case, you can find a greatest slope between two adjacent points.

Answer (score 3):

Slope is a ratio `(delta_y)/(delta_x)`, where `delta_y` and `delta_x` are measured between corresponding points.

The ratio your method computes is `(y_i - y_j)/(x_k - x_l)` for some `i`, `j`, `k` and `l` that maximize `y_i - y_j` and minimize `x_k - x_l`.  But note that neither of `(x_k, y_i)` or `(x_l, y_j)` are likely to be points from among the given `n` points.  That is, your method does not measure `delta_y` and `delta_x` at corresponding points.

To arrive at a method that works, consider sorting points in ascending order by `x` coordinate, which takes O(n log n) time. Then test, in O(n) time, whether any two points have the same `x` coordinate.  If so, an infinite or indeterminate slope exists.  Else, consider slopes between consecutive points.  One can prove that the steepest slope between *any* two of the `n` points occurs between *consecutive* points when points are sorted by ascending `x`.  Hence one can find the maximum slope in O(n) time after using O(n log n) time to sort the points.

Comment: What about y coordinates? for a slope to be max, numerator needs to be max and denominator need to be min. i feel your algorithm fails for points like (1,2) (2,3) (4,100000). your algo will choose first and second points but actually max slope occurs between second and third. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @RevanthKumar, the method computes slopes 1/1 and 99997/1, the latter being larger and getting chosen.   Why do you think it would choose the first two points?  Note, after points are sorted into ascending order by x coords, three consecutive points may represent a concave, straight, or convex curve, etc., leading to proof I mentioned.

Comment: Correction to a typo (99997/1) in prev. comment : The method computes slopes 1/1 and 99997/2, ie, slopes 1 and 49998.5, the latter being larger and getting chosen.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this works or not. The answer is open for suggestions and edits.

I will be using Divide and Conquer.

P is the set of all points.

```
MAX_SLOPE(P)
   sort all the points in P according to ascending X coordinate and break ties using ascending Y coordinates.
   print(FIND_MAX_SLOPE(P))


FIND_MAX_SLOPE(P)
   if(P.length == 2)
      if(p1.x-p2.x != 0)
         return (p1.y-p2.y)/(p1.x-p2.x)
      else
         return 0
   else
      left_p = P[0..P.length/2]
      right_p = P[P.length/2..P.length]
      slope_left = FIND_MAX_SLOPE(left_p)
      slope_right = FIND_MAX_SLOPE(right_p)
      slope_across_border = FIND_MAX_SLOPE(left_p.last UNION right_p.first)
      return MAX(slope_left,slope_right,slope_across_border)
```

Comment: After the points are sorted, just find the largest slope betwen two consecutive points.  Easy to show the max slope is attained between  two consecutive points in the x-sorted list.  No need for divide and conquer, although of course one can do it that way.